# Why doesn't javascript "this" work with "each"?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, this, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm trying to assign a class to an element upon detecting that it has a `data-voted` attribute of `"true"`, but the simple addClass line is not working.

I was using `$(this)` until I read jQuery's documentation for `each()`, and then switched to the following:

```
windowReady = ->
  jQuery -> 
    $voteLinks = $('.vote-button a')

    $voteLinks.each (i, current) ->
      if $(current).data('voted') == "true" 
        $(current).addClass('voted')

$(window).load(windowReady);
$(window).on('page:load', windowReady);

$(this)
```

---

```
windowReady = ->
  jQuery -> 
    $voteLinks = $('.vote-button a')

    $voteLinks.each ->
      if $(this).data('voted') == "true" 
        $(this).addClass('voted')

$(window).load(windowReady);
$(window).on('page:load', windowReady);
```

But even that is still not assigning a class, even though I've confirmed that it does have the `data-voted` attribute of `"true"`

CoffeesSript can be converted to Javascript at [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complement to the answer by @gwho, this implicit type conversion is in fact a [documented *feature* of JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> ### **HTML5 data-* Attributes**
>
> **Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value**
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A value
>   is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's
>   representation. For example, "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as
>   numbers (numeric value 100) but converting them would alter their
>   representation so they are left as strings. The string value "100" is
>   converted to the number 100.
>
> [...]
>
> **To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to
>   convert it, use the attr() method.**

As explained in the above quote, if you "don't like" implicit conversion, you might prefer using `attr()` (using the full attribute name) instead of `data()`:

```
windowReady = ->
  jQuery -> 
    $voteLinks = $('.vote-button a')

    $voteLinks.each (i, current) ->
      if $(current).attr('data-voted') == "true" 
        $(current).addClass('voted')
```

And if you can live with that implicit conversion:

```
windowReady = ->
  jQuery -> 
    $voteLinks = $('.vote-button a')

    $voteLinks.each (i, current) ->
      if $(current).data('voted') == true 
        $(current).addClass('voted')
```

Comment: excellent answer. thank you. I love it when answers go beyond the scope, and mention alternative likely cases thoroughly. Accepting becaues it's more thorough.

Answer (score 2):

```
windowReady = ->
  jQuery -> 
    $voteLinks = $('.vote-button a')

    $voteLinks.each (i, current) ->
      if $(current).data('voted') == true
        $(current).addClass('voted')

$(window).load(windowReady);
$(window).on('page:load', windowReady);
```

Apparently, there is some flipflopping going on behind the scenes.

The coffeescript normally takes a `==` and turns it into `===`. So according to the `===`, it should check for type as well. So when `data-voted` is `"true"`, you'd think you would have to compare it to `"true"`. NOPE.

Apparently, any data attributed that you reference or obtain via `.data()`, `"true"` or `"false"` gets turned back into boolean `true` / `false`.

Thus you have to leave the coffeescript as using `==`, which in javascript is actually `===`, which checks for the type of variable (needs to be boolean, not a string).

what implicit background craziness. Documentation, documentation, documentation. Lack of it, or not reading it wastes life. Thus documentation saves lives xp