# Rails 3 Passing a variable from link_to to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

If a user is on a form page, I am trying to throw a confirm message if they navigate away without clicking the update button.

The coffeescript code I am using is as follows

```
# used to detect if a user is navigating off a page
if form_click == true
  window.onbeforeunload = ->
    "You have unsaved data! do you really want to exit?"
```

If I use if 1 ==1 or 1 ==2 as a test case, it works perfectly fine. However, I am having diffculty in sending a variable from the link_to code to set form_click.

I have tried the following

```
<%= f.button :button, :class => 'btn-primary',
            data: {form_click: true},
            remote: true %>
```

But I am not able to pass the variable to the coffeescript code. I am definitely not proficient with javascript and coffeescript, as this probably shows, and would be grateful of any advice on how to resolve this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the generated HTML. I suspect that the `link_to` is creating something similar to:

```
<button class="btn-primary" data-form_click="true" data-remote="true"></button>
```

If so then the coffeescript you need to have would be something like:

```
$('data-form_click').click( ->
  if $(this).attr('data-form_click') == 'true'
    window.onbeforeunload = ->
      confirm("You have unsaved data! Do you really want to exit?")
)
```

The code above is off the cuff, but the main point is that the attribute on the button is a string, not a boolean, so you need to adjust accordingly.

Use the JS debugging tools to place a breakpoint so you can inspect the value of `form_click` is also another way to see what you should be comparing to.

Comment: Very good catch: _"the attribute on the button is a string"_. As `==` in CoffeeScript test for both value _and_ type (like `===` in JavaScript) OP should use the _string_ `'true'` not the boolean `true`. BTW, `attr()` always returns a string, whereas `data()` try to cast to some other native type (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321554/why-doesnt-this-javasript-work-with-each-unobstrusive-javascript-data-attr/25323927#25323927)

Comment: Huh - I've never looked at `data()` in the jQuery docs. You could reduce the condition to `if $(this).data('form_click')` - looks much nicer